# Why are there random characters missing from my urxvt terminal? (Oh now they're missing from my context menus too!)

Tags: terminal, fonts, rxvt

On my laptop, Gallium OS running on Chromebook hardware, sometimes (pretty often) a selection of characters don't want to render in my terminal ([urxvt](https://man.archlinux.org/man/urxvt.1)).  One day 'a' 'i' and 'W' are gone, another day it's 'r' 'y' 'D' and a bunch of bold characters.

[image: a screenshot of the issue]

It looks like the missing characters depend on whether the font is bold or not. There are different characters missing on different days, and I've noticed no patterns. There's *something* I have done that causes the characters to re-appear, but I haven't figured out what exactly I'm doing yet. I also have an issue, maybe related, on this laptop where the terminal suddenly won't refresh all the lines, which makes using vim pretty annoying, but switching workspaces away and back usually fixes this issue, not the missing characters issue though.

Ask and I can include more information; I just don't know what's relevant to this problem. **After we know what's causing this, I'll help in editing this question to be more relevant/findable by folks with a similar issue.**

---

Comical update: This is my home directory right now:

[image: My home directory has most of the bold characters missing]

---

Important update: **it's not just urxvt!** My context menus have no 'g'!!

[image]

Comment: »but switching workspaces away and back usually fixes this.« sounds to me like an issue related to graphics drivers/mesa and the similar. Is it only vim? Have you checked other terminals to falsify or confirm that it only happens on urxvt?

Comment: @LiveWireBT It's not only vim; `ls` will also not display those characters so it's about the terminal emulator. This error doesn't occur when I open a different terminal emulator, and when I open a different urxvt window with different settings, like with a larger font size, the error is either gone, or there are different characters missing. Opening an identical urxvt window results in the same characters being missing.

Comment: Closing and reopening the laptop lid did *not* reset the issue. Logging into a /dev/tty and returning to the graphical session did *not* reset the issue. Logging out and then back into the graphical session did reset the issue though.